# Are side boosters sometimes angled even if they are symmetrically arranged?

Tags: thrust, booster, srb

When more than one side booster is added to a first stage to increase thrust and they are distributed uniformly around the core (as opposed to those shown in links below) thrust does not seem to need to be angled. They could all point straight down (except for dynamic thrust vectoring for steering) due to symmetry.

- [Why do the shapes of these two exhaust plumes from an Atlas V 411 look different?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18159/12102)
- [How does Atlas V maintain stable flight with asymmetric solid rocket boosters?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18578/12102)

In the two images below, both from the recent NASA Spaceflight article [Beidou-3 MEO-5 and MEO-6 launched by Long March 3B](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2018/07/beidou-3m5-and-3m6-launched-by-long-march-3b/) it looks to me like the exhaust from the boosters is angled outwards, I've added an annotated, cropped, and enlarged version to better show what *I think* that I'm seeing.

Is this in fact the case for this launch, and does this happen frequently?

[image: Beidou-3 MEO-5 MEO-6 Long March 3B] [image: Beidou-3 MEO-5 MEO-6 Long March 3B]

[![Beidou-3 MEO-5 MEO-6 Long March 3B]https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJJZQ.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJJZQ.jpg)

[image: Beidou-3 MEO-5 MEO-6 Long March 3B]

Comment: Thrust vectors are probably oriented to intersect the mean center of mass. That way, if one engine fails, you don't get a sudden pitch or yaw moment from the asymmetry.

Comment: @AnthonyX I see, so approximately "torqueless". Losses due to $\cos(\theta)$ are small, and resulting radial loading due to $\sin(\theta)$ is manageable?

Comment: That configuration with the nozzles angled out was also used for the Ariane 1-4.

Comment: I think the Titans with solid boosters did this as well.

Comment: Titan diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pofU.png

Comment: [This user manual](https://www.scribd.com/document/16906525/China-s-Long-March-3B-Users-Manual#) says “The four [booster] engines can swing in tangential directions” but doesn’t appear to say *why* or mention the angle.

Comment: @Jack Tangential gimbaling would be for steering control -- swing two opposing nozzles in the same direction and the vehicle pitches or yaws; swing them in opposite direction and it rolls.

Comment: @AnthonyX You should go ahead and make that an answer.

Comment: And the [Snark](http://stellar-views.com/Photos_Missiles_Rockets.html#e6)

Comment: @AnthonyX are you interested in posting that as an answer? Here's an excellent further illustration which I think really brings your point home: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DF-SC-84-05192_cropped.jpeg If there's no activity for a while I'll probably do it myself, but it would be better if someone more familliar with the subject posted.

Comment: @Jack On rereading the manual, and looking at the guidance and control diagrams, it's the first-stage engines that are tangentially gimbaled; the booster engines are fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Caveat: This is a somewhat speculative answer based on reasoning alone*

The side booster nozzles appear to be oriented such that their thrust vectors intersect what appears to be the vehicle's nominal center of mass. The rationale for this would be to avoid or at least mitigate the effect of a thrust asymmetry if a booster fails, underperforms, or burns out prematurely. The idea would be that thrust will always be applied through the vehicle's center of mass (except where commanded as a correction or steering maneuver). Any off-center thrust would apply a torque in the pitch and/or yaw axis, which would cause the vehicle to pitch or yaw.

Comment: Would you think (also based on speculative reasoning, you have more of a handle on it than me) that this angle would/should be maintained through the entire first stage ascent? Would it make sense to stop the angle after max-Q or at a specific point of ascent?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I believe the engines on the Long March 3 boosters are only tangentially gimbaled ([as pointed out in comments above](https://www.scribd.com/document/16906525/China-s-Long-March-3B-Users-Manual#)), so the outward angle is maintained for the entire booster burn. Ditto any fixed-nozzle solid boosters. Gimbaled booster engines might be mounted so that their neutral position is canted outward like this, but during nominal flight they could steer directly aft to claw back the cosine loss.

Comment: Adding some speculation to yours: If you lose a strap-on booster early, the mission is over, catastrophically, so who cares about preventing a yaw moment then? I'll bet that they aim the strap-on's thrust through near where the expected COM is at burnout, because that's where preventing an unexpected yaw moment (from slightly early burnout on one side) could save the mission.

Comment: @WayneConrad Loss of a single strap-on booster isn't necessarily a loss-of-vehicle/loss-of-mission situation, particularly with a liquid booster, and particularly if it's not too early in the burn. A number of launches have lost an engine on ascent and continued on to partial or full success (e.g. AS-101, Apollo 6, Apollo 13, Falcon 9 CRS-1). If a booster failure causes a large yaw moment, though, it *will* be a loss-of-vehicle situation.

Comment: @RussellBorogove If you lose an engine in a multi-engine liquid stage, the remaining engines can continue to burn the fuel intended for the lost engine: you lose thrust, but you don't lose delta-V (I think).  But if you lose a strap-on solid motor, you're not getting anything out of its fuel anymore.  Now it's just weight.  Plus, how do you lose a strap-on solid motor in a benign way?  Don't they tend to burn until they either burn out more or less normally, or stop in some way that ruins your day?

Comment: @WayneConrad The question is about Long March 3, which uses liquid-fuel boosters (an early failure would leave you carrying propellant you couldn't burn, which would likely endanger the mission; a late failure might not, especially if upper stages had performance margin available). As for solids, you're probably right for 99% of cases -- but I can conceive of cases where a defective solid loses significant power without immediately exploding. In no case, however, would adding a big pitch/yaw moment to the situation improve things :)

Comment: I can't refute this speculative answer, but it seems like an expensive precaution for a likely catastrophic problem.  Seems like the cosine loses would be significant.

Comment: @Erik - I agree. It's much more likely that this is something else entirely, such as reducing plume-plume interactions.

Comment: I was incorrect about the gimbaling; it's the core engines that swivel tangentially, and the booster engines are fixed-position. The angle looks to be about 5º, which cosine is 0.996 -- implying less than half a percent wasted thrust from the boosters.