# Why are the nozzles on this rocket at an angle?

Tags: pslv

Why are the nozzles on this rocket (PSLV) at an angle?

[image]

Comment: Good closeup of the angled nozzle in a photo in this answer: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20763/6944

Comment: I think this may already have an answer here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29753/are-side-boosters-sometimes-angled-even-if-they-are-symmetrically-arranged

Comment: That duplicate id for a different rocket with very different boosters (liquid vs solid), and the answer references, characteristics of those rockets (such as the ability to control or predict burn time). While i imagine the answers will revolve around similar trade-offs, i don't think its fair to say this is a duplicate.